# How to build sql query with schema and table name given by user

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am taking input from user and then trying to build a query from that

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=LOANER-001262;'
                  'Database=classic;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("Executing!")

dbname_name = input("Enter the schema name to scan :\t")
table_name = input("Enter the table_name you want to scan:\t")
query = cursor.execute('Select * FROM '{0}' table '{1}'' .format(dbname_name,table_name))
dataframe =pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
```

Visual studio shows the syntax is not correct. How should I write it? Do I mention the column names also the same way as schema name and table name?
 I am using pyodbc

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve functionally here?  I can't really recommend creating a function that will open a cursor and read the whole table passed in by the user.

Comment: I want to connect to take input and connect to a specific schema and table. For now there is only 1 schema and table but it will expand further so I need the person running the program being able to connect and my code modifies the data after fetching it.

Comment: I can see that from the code you've created, but my question would be: why? Given that you're allow any table to be returned, then you are not going to have any control over the output of the function, e.g. the schema will be completely different.  So, my question is: what does the user need to do, why do they need to be able to read _any_ table, and what are they doing with it afterwards?  You may find that you achieve your goal better by creating specific objects and procedures within your db.

Comment: Ok, given that, I strongly recommend placing that logic in your database code rather than in the python code; you can then look at encrypting  the sensitive data at rest within SQL Server (search for articles on column encryption) and/or just not return those columns where they aren't necessary.  Alongside that you can add functionality to filter for the records that you need to return rather than a dump of the whole table which again will mitigate your risk of breaches.

Comment: Okay. But say the database has been breached, then will the attacker be able to decrypt the columns because he is already in the database? The key or however the columns are encrypted won't that be comparmised too?

Comment: It would depend on where and how you store the encryption keys for the column.  For more information on column encryption read up here:- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-2017

However, it also highlights issues with your design above - you're opening up sql injection possibilities, and due to the nature of your code, you're going to need to grant woolly permissions to lots of databases. How does pandas handle sql injection? For instance, what happens if I input into db_name ```; drop database [db];--```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=ARUNTEST;'
                  'Database=PRODUCTDATABASESSAS;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
schema_name = input("Enter the schema name to scan :\t")
table_name = input("Enter the table_name you want to scan:\t")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = cursor.execute('Select * FROM {0}. 
{1}'.format(schema_name,table_name))
#cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM {0}'.format(table_name)) -> Use this if you 
want to call the table in default schema
for row in cursor:
print(row)
```

Can you try this with above modification. By default in your connection string you are connecting to Database Classic. If the table is in default schema then schema name can be omitted as well and query should look like

select * from tablename

if you want to use it along with the schema then it should be

select * from schemaname.tablename <- note the dot

Comment: Your current solution will fail if the user enters a table (or schema) name that contains a space. Something [like this](https://pastebin.com/37ErDVRm) would be more robust.

Comment: Agree .. for any name with the space SQL server  recommends to enclose between square brackets [table name]. Something like this below
    query = cursor.execute('Select * FROM [{0}].[{1}]'.format(schema_name,table_name))

Comment: That's a bit better, but what if the table is named `shift [am/pm]` ...?

Comment: yup you're right. It fails for names like shift [am/pm].. :)

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the suggestions.. I edited so it does not fail if there is a spaace

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use this syntax
First run the query

```
Use [database_name]
```

Then run the query

```
Select * from [table_name]
```

Your database name is Stored in " dbname_name ".
Then Execute the query 
`'use  ' + dbname_name`

Comment: Can you be more specific with the 'Use' statement. Like exact synatx?

Comment: 'use ' + dbname_name